# How to create Hibernate sequence for Activiti?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, activiti

I'm switching Activiti application from in-memory database to Oracle. Scripts `activiti.oracle.create.engine.sql`, `activiti.oracle.create.history.sql`, `activiti.oracle.create.identity.sql` were successfully executed and all tables were created in the database. Application starts up fine and gets initialized without any problems. However, I get the following error when I try running one of my Activiti workflows.

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
[2016-03-09 10:02:35] [W] [SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:144] SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
[2016-03-09 10:02:35] [E] [SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:146] ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

My workflow takes a couple of variables that are persisted in JPA repository. I understand that the error is returned because Hibernate can't find the sequence for generating IDs for my variables.

My question is whether I need to create this sequence myself or it's created by one of the scripts that I missed? Thanks a lot in advance!

By the way, I have the following settings to ensure that DDL scripts are not executed on start-up

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No DDL is executed by Hibernate by default (the recommended approach for production). Also, you explicitly specified that you don't want DDL to be executed.

So, yes, you have to create the sequence yourself (again, the recommended approach for production).

Comment: Thank you, Dragan!